# Entity Framework Core requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently have 2 entities, `Player` and `Role`. I'm trying to create a migration (first migration) for these two entities.

Player.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Stargazer.Game.Roles;

namespace Stargazer.Game.Players
{
    [Table("players")]
    public class Player
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(15)]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        
        public string Motto { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Figure { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public char Gender { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public Role Role { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        [DefaultValue(500)]
        public int Coins { get; set; }
        
        public string? ConsoleMotto { get; set; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Salt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And Role.cs:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Stargazer.Game.Roles
{
    [Table("roles")]
    public class Role
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; }
        
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; }
    }
}
```

However, ONLY for `Role`, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'Role' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type call 'HasNoKey()'

However, if I remove the `Role` entity and change `Role` of `Player` to an int, it works. So the `Player` entity is correct, while the Id property of both entities is exactly the same.

How come I still get an error for the `Role` entity?

Comment: You are missing the setters on the role class properties.

Comment: @Gusman Oh my... this is embarrassing. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though it was a stupid mistake, I still want to keep it here for future reference & in case somebody makes the same mistake..

I forgot to add setters on my properties. I had to change my properties to this:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }
        
[Required]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

And then it works.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out I forgot to actually *add* the setter in the answer